# Threadpool is getting stuck at the end of execution

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

```
...
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

...

with ThreadPool(THREADS_NUMBER) as pool:
    results = pool.imap_unordered(some_function, args)
    temp = [t for t in results]
```

`some_function` is getting arguments properly, and working properly.

`temp = [t for t in results]` is just for executing, because without it it doesn't work.

I have logs in `some_function`, that show me that the thread pool is completed, all the tasks has been done (print statements showing percentage of the work args list elements processed by function), but after all the elements go through thread pool the script gets stuck in some cases. I think the reason could be the size of `args`, because I work with very big `args` lists (couple of 100K elements).

I coudn't find good complete documentation for this library, what am I doing wrong, what can be the reason for the script to get stuck? If something is not clear ask and I'll provide details

Important to note is that `some_function` has a `try`-`except` block in it, so the reason is not some basic error.

Comment: Side note: instead of `temp = [t for t in results]` you could just do `results = list(pool.imap_unordered(some_function, args))`.

Comment: Where does it get "stuck"? Can you show a reproducible piece of code to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I'm downloading images, so I send [image_url, id, number] as an argument to the function. Using print statements I can see that images were downloaded, but after the line "results = pool.imap_unordered(some_function, args)", I need to call  "temp = [t for t in results]" for the function result to actually execute or something like that, I don't understand it very well. So I think it gets stuck on the line "temp = [t for t in results]", because I have print statements after that line, but they are not printing anything

Comment: It's a part of very big program, and not easily reproducable, because I download 500K images to google cloud storage, one original size and one thumbnail that I make in the function.

Comment: It is very likely that *some_function()* is stuck working on a download. Providing all the threads terminate without exception the code shown will not get "stuck"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this really answers the question.

The question suggests that there might be a problem if the number of items in the iterable passed to *imap_unordered()* is very large.

So here's an example with 1 million values which is shown to execute normally:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from time import perf_counter

def process(n):
    return n // 2 # just do something trivial

def main():
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        temp = list(pool.imap_unordered(process, range(1_000_000)))
        print(f'{len(temp):,}', *temp[:5], *temp[-5:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = perf_counter()
    main()
    end = perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.4}s')
```

**Output:**

```
1,000,000 0 0 1 1 2 499997 499998 499998 499999 499999
Duration=2.188s
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if the size of the argument list is not the problem, what else can possibly be?

Comment: @SamvelMinasyan As I said in an earlier comment, it's highly likely that one or more threads (execution of *some_function()*) is not terminating

Comment: I thought opening it like this  "with Threadpool() as pool" automatically solves that problem, how I can make sure that the threads are terminating?

Comment: @SamvelMinasyan That depends very much on the implementation of *some_function()*. As you're downloading data from the web you should perhaps consider using some form of timeout. However, without seeing your code it's impossible to offer concrete suggestions

Comment: thank you for your answer. The strange part is that the code sometimes works and sometimes not, for basically the same arguments. I'll continue fixing it, using your suggestions